Socle in commutative ring
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $D$ be a $R$-module. The idealization (Nagata) $R(+)D $ is defined by $R(+)D= \{ (r,d): r\in R, d \in D \}$ with the operation $(r_1,d_1)+(r_2,d_2)=(r_1+r_2,d_1+d_2)$ and $(r_1,d_1).(r_2,d_2)=(r_1r_2,r_1d_2+r_2d_1)$ for $r_1, r_2\in R$ and $d_1,d_2 \in D$.
We know if $Q$ is an ideal of a ring $R$, then $Q+D=\{ (q,d): q\in Q ,d \in D \}$ is an ideal of $R(+)D$
I need prove $Soc(R (+) D) \subseteq Soc(R) (+) Soc(D)$.
Context:

I am studying the structure of the ring $ R(+)M $ and its relation to the socles of $R$ and $M$.
My intuition is that any minimal ideal of $ R(+)M $ must project onto a minimal ideal of $R$ or a minimal submodule of $M$, but I am struggling to formalize this idea.
This question is part of my efforts to understand the interaction between ring and module structures.

My Attempts:
I have analyzed the definitions of minimal ideals and minimal submodules in $ R(+)M $ but have yet to establish a clear connection between them and the socles of $R$ and $M$. Specifically:

If $I$ is a minimal ideal of $ R(+)M $, how does it relate to $Soc(R) $ and $Soc(M))$?
I have considered direct projections but need help understanding their implications.

Any guidance or step-by-step insights to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

I have considered direct projections but need help understanding their implications. Text explanation or it didn't happen.. If you get that in, i think your question is likely to be reopened.
